# Magento 1 : Issue with Template override

Tags: magento-1.9, template, sales-order, overrides

How to override this file in magento 1 using module ?

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/items/grid.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a layout XML file inside of your module. You need to have a section in your module's config.xml like this to let Magento load your module's layout XML (path: app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodulename.xml):

```
<config>
    [...]
    <frontend>
        [...]
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodulename_layout module="MyModuleName">
                    <file>mymodulename.xml</file>
                </mymodulename_layout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

In this layout XML file you can reference the specific blocks and change their template.

```
<layout>
    <sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales.order.view">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>mymodulename/sales/order/view.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_view>
    <sales_order_print>
        <reference name="sales.order.print">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>mymodulename/sales/order/print.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_print>
</layout>
```